# prevent the logged in uuser from accesing the login page asp.net mvc applicaion

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my controller. Its not working for logged in users preventing access to the login page. Please help me out. I have used the request.Is Authenicated and User.Identity Methods in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Main","Home");
    }
   else if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View(model);
    }

   else if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
        if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");
    }
    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Invalid Credentials.");
    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

    return this.View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this line in my code

bool test = Request.IsAuthenticated;

and it always came up false.  However I am using windows Authentication in my application.  If you have a logon screen I'm assuming you are not.  I found this post on the site about always receiving a false value from Request.IsAuthenticated.  Obviously your code should work IF you are receiving the right value from this flag.  If this is not the answer let me know I might research a little more.

[Request.IsAuthenticated is always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536955/request-isauthenticated-is-always-false)

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i do:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated
{
    get
    {
        return this._context.User != null && 
               this._context.User.Identity != null &&
               this._context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```